# react-native build failed, 'native_modules.gradle' line: 182

Tags: react-native

I init a new project using react native 0.61.2 , using react-native init proj command, after that when I try to react-native run-android, the build fails with this error :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:Script '..\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 182
> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating script.
>   Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
>
>   The current character read is 'D' with an int value of 68
>   Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
>   line number 1
>   index number 0
>   as i mentioned, it's a fresh project.
>   any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: remove node module folder and reinstall it again !

Comment: @Maleking, i did, but no luck , same problem

Comment: after the re-install of node_modules make sure to navigate to android folder run gradle clean command

Comment: tried gradlew clean.. Build failed with same error.. as i said its a fresh project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today and noticed that react recently released new versions to react-native and react.

I downgraded to versions i know work properly which are:

```
"react": "~16.8.0",
"react-native": "~0.60.0"
```

cleared all cache and the project loads correctly.

in order to do so change the dependencies in your `package.json` file

then delete your `node_modules` directory, `package.lock` file and run `npm cache clean`

finally run `npm i`

perhaps there are still issues in the new releases.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, actually i also downgraded to 0.60.0 yesterday after i faded up with this error, do you have any idea where to report this issue?

Comment: there are open issues in the react repos about this, this is not just us feeling this :)

Answer (score 1):

I am aslo facing the  same issue. Downgrading works, however i have two other projects that r working fine and they are react native 0.61.2

Only new projects are giving this error. I read in some blogs that removing react community cli from global and trying again might do the trick.

Will try that tomorrow and post my findings.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue in a fresh project with RN 0.64.0. The project was created inside a monorepo that was using [Yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces). In my case, Yarn had moved or "hoisted" the `@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle` file to the root `node_modules` directory.

The Android project's `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` files are expecting the `@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle` file to be in the RN project's `node_modules` directory and not the repo's root `node_modules` directory.

Try updating line 2 of `settings.gradle` to something like:

```
apply from: file("../../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
```

And line 222 of `build.gradle` to something like:

```
apply from: file("../../../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Obviously, you will need to adjust how many leading `../` you add to the path depending on how nested your project is.

You could also look into using the [nohoist](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/) options available with Yarn to keep packages from moving around.

Comment: Thanks! I can now clean the project! Let's see if I can build it now...

Answer (score 0):

Look for mistakes in your `AndroidManifest.xml`!!!

For me, I solved this by replacing the character **”** with **"**
(And also read some people telling that unclosed tags did that too)
As dumb as it looks, I got to this error from following a tutorial.

(tip: VS code would often show these quotes in different colors, unless you have installed another XML files extension)